# Need help fixing CSS for a GTK theme for Gnome Shell

Tags: css, gnome-shell

Using Gnome 3.8 I am now using [FlatStudio](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/FlatStudio?content=154296) as my GTK theme. After a few tweaks within `/themes/FlatStudioDark/gtk-3.0/`, I noticed this:

[image: some inconsistencies]

Is there any way to find classes and CSS applied to each part of a window ? I am looking for the same thing which Google Chrome developer tools provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [GTKParasite](https://github.com/chipx86/gtkparasite) which has a port to GTK3, but you will need to build it from source then :)